# Button to add to a group

Tags: datagrid, devexpress

## Context

I have a grid which is grouped by 'Date' and then by 'Time':

[image]

## Issue

I'd like to have a button per group which is used to add an entry to the group.

## Example

For example, if I could have a button labeled `Add` in the group line, that would be nice:

[image]

Is this possible? I.e. is there a way to embed a button in the group line?

## Other options

If this is not possible, what's the recommended way of having the user indicate that they'd like to add to a given group?

Here's a couple of workarounds that aren't ideal:

- Select a row in a group. Have a button outside the grid which basically does:

  - "add a new record to the group that the selected row is in".
- Each row has a column for an 'Add' button. This is very awkward, but would work.

## Other grid systems

Coda.io supports grouping and has a `+` button per group which allows you to add entries:

[image]

## Notes

I've also tagged this question with `datagrid` so if folks know of other grid libraries which do support adding to groups, feel free to suggest them. I'm still evaluating options.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I need such functionality as well, but DX doesn't offer it.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, HTML5/JS, Blazor etc?

Comment: @brendon The free JS version

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič, it looks like this is possible in Webix Treeview. See this codepen for example: https://codepen.io/dharmatech/full/mdWGbox Click on 'Group by Date Time' and notice the buttons in the group headers.